# Do cheap window films really reflect/reject infrared?

Tags: film

I see online films sold for about 15 Euro/dollars for 50x300 cm that claim 70% visible light transmission, 90+% UV rejection and 50+% infrared rejection.

Do these products actually work? Are there tests? I believe that the value for the visible light transmission and UV rejection is realistic, but infrared has longer wavelengths and I'm more skeptical.

I'm interested specifically in the infrared rejection because I'd like to improve the cooling of my car and of my attic in summer.

Comment: I can find no tests, but you can test yourself....https://www.ebay.com/itm/IR-UV-VL-window-tint-solar-film-window-film-transmission-meter-tester-IR-950nm-/252169471598

Comment: Also see this....https://windowtintingblog.net/tag/ir-window-film-facts/

Comment: @Moab I ordered Arduino modules for visible, UV and IR detection. I'll measure the ratio before/after film.